# One bind "ended" for all videos [html5]

Tags: html, video, bind

i need to increment a variable each time a video has been watched (no matter which one), so i can display an ad when this variable reach 10.

Actually i bind every video using their ID.

```
<video id="1">...</video>
<video id="2">...</video>
<video id="3">...</video>

$('#'+idVideo).bind('ended',function(){ /* each time i append a video, i do this */
        WATCHED_VIDEOS++;
        // displayAd() when WATCHED_VIDEOS reach 10....
});
```

I tried this line `$('video').bind('ended',function(){...});` instead of binding every video but it doesn't work.

Anyone has a solution to accomplish this using only one bind? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
<video id="1">...</video>
<video id="2">...</video>
<video id="3">...</video>
<script>
    var total_ended = 0;
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    for (i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
        videos[i].onended = function() {
            total_ended++;
            console.log('Total videos ended: ' + total_ended);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xvLmam41/

hope that helps.

Comment: This is approximately what i did... So i cannot use only one bind or end-event for all videos? i must do it for each one?